# angularjs object list not binding to ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, data-binding

I am using angular 1.5.5 with ui router 0.2.14. I have the view of employee list to be displayed. EmployeeList template is as follows:

```html
    <table class="employeeListContainer">
    <tr ng-repeat="employee in employees">
        <td>
            <a ng-bind="employee.EmployeeId" class="employeeId"></a>
            <!--ui-sref="employeeDetails{ employeeId: employee.EmployeeId }"-->
        </td>
        <td ng-bind="employee.FirstName"></td>
        <td ng-bind="employee.LastName"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="3" class="paging">
            <button ng-disabled="!IsPrevButtonEnabled" ng-click="prevPage()" class="prev-next">&lt;</button>&nbsp;
            <span ng-bind="PageNumber"></span>&nbsp;
            <button ng-disabled="!IsNextButtonEnabled" ng-click="nextPage()" class="prev-next">&gt;</button>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="3" class="paging">
            <span ng-bind="ErrorMessage" ng-show="IsError"></span>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I have configured the app as follows:

```js
var app = angular.module('app', ['ui.router']);
app.config(function ($urlRouterProvider, $stateProvider, $httpProvider) {
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
    $stateProvider.state('employeeList', {
        url: '/List',
        templateUrl: '../../Templates/EmployeeList.html',
        controller: 'EmployeeListController',
        resolve: {
            employeeListRs: function (dataService) {
                var employeeListRq = getEmployeeListRqInit();
                return dataService.callApi('GetEmployees', 'post', [employeeListRq])
                    .then(function (data) { return data.data; });
            },
            employeeListRq: function(){
                return getEmployeeListRqInit();
            },
            greeting: function ($q, $timeout) {
                var deferred = $q.defer();
                $timeout(function () {
                    deferred.resolve('Hello!');
                }, 1000);
                return deferred.promise;
            }
        }
    });
    $stateProvider.state('default', {
        url: '/',
        //templateUrl: '../../Templates/EmployeeList.html',
        controller: 'defaultController'
    });
    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common = {};
    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.post = {};
    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.put = {};
    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.patch = {};

    var getEmployeeListRqInit = function () {
        return {
            PageNumber: 1,
            PageSize: 10,
            SessionId: "123"
        };
    }
});
```

dataService is a service that is wrapper to the original $http.post call. Controller code is as follows:

```js
app.controller('EmployeeListController', function ($scope, employeeListRq, employeeListRs, greeting) {
    $scope.PageNumber = employeeListRq.PageNumber;
    $scope.PageSize = employeeListRq.PageSize;
    $scope.IsError = !employeeListRs.IsSuccess;
    $scope.TotalCount = (employeeListRs.EmployeeList == null) ? 0 : employeeListRs.EmployeeList.TotalCount;
    $scope.employees = (employeeListRs.EmployeeList == null) ? null : employeeListRs.EmployeeList.Employees;
    
    if ($scope.employees = null) return 1;
    var remainder = $scope.TotalCount % $scope.PageSize;
    var pageNumber = Math.floor($scope.TotalCount / $scope.PageSize);
    var lastPageNumber = remainder > 0 ? pageNumber + 1 : pageNumber;
    $scope.IsNextButtonEnabled = $scope.PageNumber != lastPageNumber;
    $scope.IsPrevButtonEnabled = $scope.PageNumber != 1;

    $scope.IsLoading = false;
    $scope.ErrorMessage = employeeListRs.IsSuccess ? '' : employeeListRs.ErrorMessage;
});
```

I see while debugging in chrome that $scope.employees is set to an array containing 10 objects all with proper fields and values. Also the IsPrevButtonEnabled and IsNextButtonEnabled are set perfectly. The binding is reflected on UI too, perfectly. 
But I don't see the table containing employees list. Any suggestions on what I am missing?

Note: I don't get any error on console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few things you can try:

(1)  Not saying yours is incorrect, but the preferred way to bind the data would be to use expressions.  So, instead of this:

```
<td ng-bind="employee.FirstName"></td>
```

try this:

```
<td>{{employee.FirstName}}</td>
```

(2)  This line looks suspicious in your controller:

```
if ($scope.employees = null) return 1;
```

It looks like you are assigning a null value to $scope.employees instead of checking for null.  I/my teams try to use angular.isDefined($scope.employees) when we want to check for existence.

What are you trying to accomplish with that line?

(3)  This looks a little different than how I use services and how I see others use them:

```
resolve: {
        employeeListRs: function (dataService)
```

It looks to me that employeeListRs returns a promise.

What I typically do is call the service (my angular service which in turn calls the $http service) from inside the controller and then handle the response (both expected and error responses).  From there I push the data into the controller's model. I haven't yet mixed service calls into my state machines - I let the controllers make the service calls.

(4)  What is inside this css class - employeeListContainer?  Could there be something there hiding your table?  You might want to share your html and css as well.

Comment: You are a genius! It's true what they say. A typo can make a huge difference. Lesson learned :) Thanks!